# Why do resistors in parallel with each diode in a diode string prevent high voltage damage?

Tags: diodes

The book said that we can increase the reverse blocking capability, and when we connect a resistor in parallel with each diode it can protect the diodes from high voltage damage.

[image]

Why?

Parallel connected resistors can't divide the voltage, but the series connected can.

I mean if the the voltage in the  \$A\$ point,\$V_a\$, is \$100V\$, then the voltage in the \$B\$ point, \$V_b\$, should be \$100V\$, too,\$R_2\$ can't decrease \$V_a\$.

So why do lots of books or websites say to connect a resistor in parallel with each diode to protect the diodes from high voltage damage?

Comment: A and B labels are both on the same net. The voltage between A and B must always be zero.  What matters is the voltage that appears _across_ each of the two diodes which, according to your diagram, must also be the voltage that appears across each of the two resistors.

Answer (score 4):

Diodes have reverse leakage current which means that each diode will behave a bit like a resistor of high value. If the reverse leakage current in each diode is not identical it means that their effective resistances will not be identical either and so the reverse voltage drop across each diode will differ.

If, for example, you had 60 volt diodes on your 100 volt supply and the voltage drops turned out to be 70 volt and 30 volt then one of the diodes would be stressed and may fail. Adding the parallel resistors with values lower than the diode equivalent reverse biased resistance will prevent the overvoltage by balancing the voltage drop across each diode.

Answer (score 4):

The answer by Transistor is correct for the question as asked. However, resistors only work for DC reverse bias or slowly rising reverse bias.

Diodes can have quite large and different junction capacitances, and these may unbalance the reverse string under a rapidly rising reverse voltage, faster than the (usually) large resistors can equalise the charge. Capacitors should be added as well to swamp the differences.

Ordinary junction diodes have quite significant charge storage, and this can vary between diodes. If a reverse current is applied abruptly, the diodes stay on until this charge is exhausted, and then the fastest diode turns off first. This diode will then be subject to the whole of the reverse voltage. Relatively large capacitors will slow the rate of rise of voltage across the first diode, until the other ones catch up.

Large capacitors and resistors across a diode string add cost and complexity, and decrease the efficiency of the rectifier. These Rs and Cs cannot make the balancing perfect, they will only improve it, so the string must still include enough diodes to exceed the wanted reverse voltage by some margin.

In practice, diode strings are often made with multiple silicon diodes from the same batch, with enough used so that the nominal reverse breakdown of the string is at least twice what is needed. On the first few applications of reverse voltage, the fastest and lowest capacity diodes will fail, invariably to short-circuit, leaving enough survivors to carry the target voltage. Obviously this is only sensible for strings with many diodes, there would be little point with only two diodes.

Comment: This is a much better answer than mine. I've never seen an application where sacrificial diodes were included!

Comment: @Transistor Standard technique if you want to make a 30 kV rectifier from 1N4007s, the diodes cost an order of magnitude less than suitable Rs and Cs would.

Comment: "invariably to short-circuit" - is this really always true? The only mode of failure is short circuit?

Comment: @Arsenal Yes, almost always, for high voltage silicon power diodes. The breakdown from an overvoltage fuses the entire junction into a single conducting blob. With a sufficiently high reverse energy, it's possible to physically blow the diode apart (a popular failure mode with LEDs, where a Light Emitting Diode becomes a Dark Emitting Monode) but that's fairly easy to spot. For low voltage diodes, signal diodes, other materials, it's not as true.